# Is there any other tools to test iPhone application

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I want to test my iPhone application for memory leaks...

I have used xcode performance tool with leaks...

can you pls tell me is there any other tools in which i can test my application

Thanks for any help

Comment: xcode has a good tool to find memory leaks, why do you need an other app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know the static analyzer? Hit Shift + Command + A (Build and Analyze) in Xcode and it analyzes your code for memory leaks. It's based on the clang static analyzer from the llvm project. http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/